# Can I nest areas in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, areas

I want the follow URLs in my MVC application:

```
/Admin/Accounts/Groups
/Admin/Accounts/Users
```

I know I could create an Area named `Admin`, and then create `Groups` and `Users` controllers inside that area.

Could I instead create nested areas? (An Area named `Admin`, and inside of this area an Area named `Accounts`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish your desired URL above, just specify it in the route configuration of your "Admin" area like this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/Accounts/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

No need to create Groups or Users controllers.

Comment: This may have solved the user's problem but it doesn't answer the question.